# forward subdomain with route 53 to ec2 instance with node js

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-ec2, node.js, amazon-route53

I have node js serving both root site (non prefix) and app.mydomain with node js subdomain npm .
how can I point to both of them using Route 53? as for now the root domain get request's from Route 53 using A record to the appropriate Elastic IP.(specifically its a www.mydomain )
how can forward a request to node js with the app sub domain prefix?
thanks in advance

Comment: Why not just add another `A` record? If not that, what specifically do you need?

Comment: Another A record with appropriate prefix didn't work, it was another root website. node js responded to naked root

Comment: Are your root nodejs and app nodejs servers running on the same instance? If so, are they within one nodejs server or two nodejs servers running on different ports?

Comment: one instance, one nodejs server the same port, all the routing as for now is based on subdomain nmp. if this issue wont be resolved soon ill probably change to another instance. is there any suggestion for the current architecture? Cheers :)

Comment: If it's on the same instance, within the same nodejs server (ie. on the same port), then there's nothing route 53 can do to help you. As long as both your root and app domains have the same A record, the route53 config is correct. You need to configure your nodejs server to observe the `Host:` header and deliver the correct contents.